# Stop sympy from inverting variables order in displayed latex equation? or control the order?

Tags: python, latex, sympy

There's the annoying issue of sympy that by default to completely inverts the order of the displayed Equation I write in comparison to the typed order like so:

[inversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbcv6.png)

As I expect to receive it like so:

[Right_Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPGF3.png)

Is there a way to do that already?
I've seen some similar question from more than 5 years ago asking about similar things of preserving the order or variables but no good answer there.
Some people clain that sympy can't do that but I can't wrap my head around how no one make a simple single function solution to display equations right as that is one of the main feature that sympy should provide to understand equations as the ORDER DOES MATTER for understanding the equation.

Any simple solution to print the original preserved latex representation of the equation in jupyter lab with sympy?

Answer (score 2):

Sympy will order the variables in alphabetical order, which you have seen. If you're working with variables where the order of multiplication is important, such as matrices, then your variables are not commutative. You can tell sympy that the variables are not commutative when you create the symbols by passing the keyword argument `commutative=False` (the default is `True`). Note: noncommutativity only applies to multiplication and not addition.

```py
import sympy as sp

N_PA, V_VSR, R_S1, V_OUT, V_F, N_PS = sp.symbols("N_PA V_VSR R_S1 V_OUT V_F N_PS", commutative=False)

Eq1 = sp.Eq(R_S1, ((V_VSR*R_S1*N_PA)/((V_OUT + V_F)*N_PS-(V_VSR*N_PA))))
Eq1
```

[image]

Because the variables are not commutative, it also uses the inverse rather than the numerator-denominator division format.

Comment: Well but after you commutative=False the equation is still distorted and displayed not according to the user typed order...

Comment: @Mike (1) What do you mean by distorted? (2) Why does it matter if it's in _exactly_ the same order as it's written? It's still mathematically valid.

Comment: The order does matter for doc purposes and understanding it's just nice when you can use sympy to also display the reference equation before solving it.